# WPF GridSplitter with multiple siblings not doen't work as expected

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I searched around and didn't find similar question on the forum. I have the following WPF code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="238.788" Width="406.407">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox1 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter"/>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5"  Grid.Row="1" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
            <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="I want this black section have fixed height while moving the GridSplitter" Foreground="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox2 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When the user drags the grid splitter, only the two textbox should be resized. But what I got is like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: It could be done with the last 2 rows inside a nested Grid.

Comment: Have a look at [`GridResizeDirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridresizedirection?view=netframework-4.8) and [`GridResizeBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridresizebehavior?view=netframework-4.8) and try to combine these enum values with `GridSplitter` alignment. But I don't think that you can do that without adding an additional container

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that the problem is not because GridSplitter can only split two before and after siblings, it's the wrong RowDefinition! In the code snippet of the question, the first and forth RowDefinition are set to `Height="*"`, which force them to split the additional space evenly. That's why when you drag the splitter and the first and forth row always keep the same height. If I change them according to the following setting, it just works as expected.

```
   <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150" />
            <RowDefinition Height="5" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox1 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter" />
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" Grid.Row="1" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
            <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="I want this black section have fixed height while moving the GridSplitter"
                       Foreground="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox2 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter" />
    </Grid>
```

So no need to nest any more.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `StackPanel` and the second `TextBox` into a single `Panel`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox1 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter"/>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5"  Grid.Row="1" />
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="I want this black section have fixed height while moving the GridSplitter" Foreground="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox2 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Does GridSplitter only split left right or up down two elements? It seems if GridSplitter have more than 3 siblings (self included), it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, set `VerticalAlignment="Center"` by the ´StackPanel´

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox1 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter"/>
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5"  Grid.Row="1" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="I want this black section have fixed height while moving the GridSplitter" Foreground="Aqua" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox2 should be resized while moving the GridSplitter"/>
</Grid>
```